# Rust: Getting error in cloning the sender

Tags: rust

In both the cases i have cloned the sender the first one works fine while in the second one i'm getting error.

Can anyone share any resource related to the error i'm getting or how can i rectify the error.

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::process::Command;
use crossbeam_channel::{bounded, unbounded};
use std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel;

fn main(){
    let (s, r) = sync_channel(3);
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for i in 0..3 {
        let s = s.clone();
        let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
            s.send(i).unwrap();
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    for _ in 0..3 {
        let received = r.recv().unwrap();
        println!("{}", received);
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join();
    }
}
```

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::process::Command;
use crossbeam_channel::{bounded, unbounded};
use std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel;

fn main(){
    let (s, r) = sync_channel(3);
    let thread1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        s.send(1).unwrap();
    }); 
    let s = s.clone();
    let thread2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        s.send(2).unwrap();
    });
    let thread3 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let received = r.recv().unwrap();
        println!("{}", received);
    });
}
```

Here is the error which i'm getting in second case:

```rust
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s`
  --> src/main.rs:82:13
   |
78 |     let (s, r) = sync_channel(3);
   |          - move occurs because `s` has type `SyncSender<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
79 |     let thread1 = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                 ------- value moved into closure here
80 |         s.send(1).unwrap();
   |         - variable moved due to use in closure
81 |     }); 
82 |     let s = s.clone();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Comment: Please post code as text rather than as a image

Answer (score 1):

The error information has explained the reason.

In your first code snippet, each move happens after a corresponding clone, so the original `s` keeps valid.

In your second code snippet, the first clone of `s` happens after it's been moved, so it's invalid.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. So, Can you please tell me how can i remove the error.

Comment: like clone `s` before the first two spawns using different names (s1, s2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, **the compiler's error message tells you exactly what the issue is**: you're moving the sender into the first closure (line 79). Therefore by line 82 `s` is invalid (moved-from), and can't be used in any way (cloning or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error in the second case we should clone all the senders at the top of the thread from where we have started to send the data.

Here's the rectified code for the second case:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::process::Command;
use crossbeam_channel::{bounded, unbounded};
use std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel;

fn main(){
    let (s, r) = sync_channel(3);
    let s1 = s.clone();
    let thread1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        s.send(1).unwrap();
    }); 
    let thread2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        s1.send(2).unwrap();
    });
    let thread3 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let received = r.recv().unwrap();
        println!("{}", received);
    });
}
```